# JQuery Function error "is not a function" when use other library

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I use Magento in my site and jQuery files already in header, and I add JS file in body area. This is my code:

```
<a href="listmessage" data-type="iframe" class="venobox_custom">Message</a>

<script type="text/javasciprt" src="<?php echo $actual_link;?>/js/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.venobox_custom').venobox({
            framewidth: '400px',        // default: ''
            frameheight: '450px',       // default: ''
            border: '10px',             // default: '0'
            bgcolor: 'white',           // default: '#fff'
            titleattr: 'data-title',    // default: 'title'
            numeratio: true,            // default: false
            infinigall: true            // default: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

All files loaded successful, but display this JS error: `TypeError: $(...).venobox is not a function`.

I use library from http://lab.veno.it/venobox/

Comment: You have a typo: `type="text/javasciprt"`

Comment: Your library is not included properly... rest all is good. just correct javascript spelling